# Split a data frame column containing a list into multiple columns using dplyr (or otherwise)

Tags: r, dplyr

Consider the following example data

```
library(dplyr)
tmp <- mtcars %>%
    group_by(cyl) %>%
    summarise(mpg_sum = list(summary(mpg)))
```

such that `mpg_sum` contains the min, 1st quartile, median, mean, 3rd quartile, and max of the `mpg` variable by groups in `cyl`.

How do I unpack this column into 6 columns with appropriate column names with dplyr, or otherwise?

Comment: You can also use `library(broom); mtcars %>% group_by(cyl) %>% do(tidy(summary(.$mpg)))`

Comment: can you please post this as an answer. I've alway sbeen interested in broom.

Comment: Variation on a theme: `mtcars %>%
    group_by(cyl) %>% summarise(summary = list(broom::tidy(summary(mpg)))) %>% tidyr::unnest()`

Comment: @Alex, I posted as answer

Comment: This answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/52352912/4269699 to a very similar problem addresses the specific example in this question and might be useful. It doesn't address the more general problem of unpacking a list-column into multiple columns.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

We can use `data.table`.  Convert the 'data.frame' to 'data.table' (`as.data.table(mtcars)`), grouped by 'cyl', we get the `summary` of 'mpg' and convert it to `list`

```
library(data.table)
as.data.table(mtcars)[, as.list(summary(mpg)), by = cyl]
#    cyl Min. 1st Qu. Median  Mean 3rd Qu. Max.
#1:   6 17.8   18.65   19.7 19.74   21.00 21.4
#2:   4 21.4   22.80   26.0 26.66   30.40 33.9
#3:   8 10.4   14.40   15.2 15.10   16.25 19.2
```

---

Or using *only* `dplyr`, after grouping by 'cyl', we use `do` to do the same operation as above.

```
library(dplyr)
mtcars %>%
     group_by(cyl) %>%
     do(data.frame(as.list(summary(.$mpg)), check.names=FALSE) )
#   cyl  Min. 1st Qu. Median  Mean 3rd Qu.  Max.
#  <dbl> <dbl>   <dbl>  <dbl> <dbl>   <dbl> <dbl>
#1     4  21.4   22.80   26.0 26.66   30.40  33.9
#2     6  17.8   18.65   19.7 19.74   21.00  21.4
#3     8  10.4   14.40   15.2 15.10   16.25  19.2
```

Or using `purrr`

```
library(purrr)
mtcars %>% 
     slice_rows("cyl") %>% 
     select(mpg) %>%
     by_slice(dmap, summary, .collate= "cols")
```

Comment: this looks really good... the auto naming from `data.table` is much better as you don't have to specify check.names

Comment: so there is a problem with `dplyr::do` in the sense that it drops all columns except the grouping one. For example, `mtcars %>% group_by(cyl) %>% mutate(mpg_sum = list(summary(mpg)))`. If you unpack this list the other columns of the table disappear.

Comment: It looks like `data.table` provides a solution that `dplyr` cannot, as you can very easily assign multiple outputs of one function call to multiple named columns.

Comment: Here is what I am trying to do in `dplyr` but cannot: http://stackoverflow.com/a/38236959/2109289

Comment: purrr no longer includes `by_slice()` and `dmap()`. See [change log purrr 0.2.2.9000](http://purrr.tidyverse.org/news/index.html)

Answer (score 10):

As commented, you can also use the `tidy` function from package `broom`:

```
library(broom)
mtcars %>% group_by(cyl) %>% do(tidy(summary(.$mpg)))
# Source: local data frame [3 x 7]
# Groups: cyl [3]
# 
#     cyl minimum    q1 median  mean    q3 maximum
#   (dbl)   (dbl) (dbl)  (dbl) (dbl) (dbl)   (dbl)
# 1     4    21.4 22.80   26.0 26.66 30.40    33.9
# 2     6    17.8 18.65   19.7 19.74 21.00    21.4
# 3     8    10.4 14.40   15.2 15.10 16.25    19.2
```

Answer (score 4):

*(or otherwise)* option using `sapply()`:

```
t(sapply(split(mtcars$mpg, mtcars$cyl), summary))
```

Comment: Or `do.call(rbind, by(mtcars$mpg, mtcars$cyl, FUN = summary))`

Answer (score 4):

Another option

```
with(data = mtcars,by(mpg,cyl,FUN = summary))
```