# Efficient assignment of a function with multiple outputs in dplyr mutate or summarise

Tags: r, dplyr

I've noticed a lot of examples here which uses `dplyr::mutate` in combination with a function returning multiple outputs to create multiple columns. For example:

```
tmp <- mtcars %>%
    group_by(cyl) %>%
    summarise(min = summary(mpg)[1],
              median = summary(mpg)[3],
              mean = summary(mpg)[4],
              max = summary(mpg)[6])
```

Such syntax however means that the `summary` function is called 4 times, in this example, which does not seem particularly efficient. What ways are there to efficiently assign a list output to a list of column names in `summarise` or `mutate`?

For example, from a previous question: [Split a data frame column containing a list into multiple columns using dplyr (or otherwise)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38177908/split-a-data-frame-column-containing-a-list-into-multiple-columns-using-dplyr-o), I know that you can assign the output of `summary` as a list and then split it using `do(data.frame(...))`, however this means that you have to then add the column names later and the syntax is not as pretty.

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/q/21630406/4241780 'Return a list in dplyr mutate'.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `tie` package from Romain Francois can do this very neatly

```
devtools::install_github("romainfrancois/tie")
library('tidyverse')
library('tie')

tmp <- mtcars %>%
  group_by(cyl) %>%
  bow( tie(min, median, mean, max) := summary(mpg)[c(1,3,4,6)] )
```

Note the use of `:=` rather than `=`.

This issue of using functions that return vectors (not scalars) inside summarise is considered by the tidyverse team here https://github.com/tidyverse/dplyr/issues/154 and in further posts referenced within.

Answer (score 3):

This addresses your example, but perhaps not your principal question. In the case you showed, you could rewrite this as:

```
tmp <- mtcars %>%
    group_by(cyl) %>%
    summarise_each(funs(min, median, mean, max), mpg)
```

This is more efficient, taking about 40% as much time to run:

```
microbenchmark(mtcars %>%
                 group_by(cyl) %>%
                 summarise_each(funs(min, median, mean, max), mpg), 
                                times = 1000L)


 mtcars %>% group_by(cyl) %>% summarise_each(funs(min, median,mean, max), mpg)
      min       lq     mean   median       uq      max neval
 2.002762 2.159464 2.330703 2.216719 2.271264 7.771477  1000


microbenchmark(mtcars %>%
    group_by(cyl) %>%
    summarise(min = summary(mpg)[1],
              median = summary(mpg)[3],
              mean = summary(mpg)[4],
              max = summary(mpg)[6]), times = 1000L)

 mtcars %>% group_by(cyl) %>% summarise(min = summary(mpg)[1], median = summary(mpg)[3], mean = summary(mpg)[4], max = summary(mpg)[6])
      min      lq     mean   median       uq      max neval
 4.967731 5.21122 5.571605 5.360689 5.530197 13.26596  1000
```

However, there are certainly other cases whether this will not address the problem.

EDIT:

The `do()` function can solve this. e.g.

```
by_cyl <- group_by(mtcars, cyl) %>%
        do(mod = summary(.)[c(1,4,6),])
```

Comment: hi, thank you for this, but as you correctly point out, it doesn't address my principal question.

Comment: @Alex added edit that should address what you're looking for.

Comment: That doesn't work, the results get assigned to one column

Comment: @Alex No, they get assigned to a list, by_cyl$mod . All the results are in there and can be accessed.

Answer (score 2):

I cannot find a suitable solution in `dplyr` that lets you assign names in a easy to remember way. I find the following `data.table` solution acceptable, if a bit wordy:

```
data.table(mtcars) %>%
    .[, setattr(as.list(summary(mpg)[c(1,3,4,6)]), 
        "names", c("min", "median", "mean", "max")),
         by = cyl]
```

This is derived from [akrun's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38177980/2109289), where by:

```
data.table(mtcars) %>%
    .[, as.list(summary(mpg)[c(1,3,4,6)]), by = cyl]
```

automatically assigns the output of the function into 4 columns. Thus the only thing left is to rename the columns appropriately using the `setattr` function.

Note that the output of `summary` is not a list, therefore has to be coerced to a list for this to work.

Answer (score 1):

I managed to do it this way. It works reasonably fast with a 45 million row dataset I own.

```
tmp <- mtcars %>%
  group_by(cyl) %>%
  do(data.frame(t(as.matrix(summary(.$mpg)[c(1, 3, 4, 6)]))))

Source: local data frame [3 x 5]
Groups: cyl [3]

    cyl  Min. Median  Mean  Max.
  <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1     4  21.4   26.0 26.66  33.9
2     6  17.8   19.7 19.74  21.4
3     8  10.4   15.2 15.10  19.2
```

Answer (score 1):

This can also be accomplished using `tidyr::nest` and `purrr::map`. Note, the output returned by summary needs to be converted from a named vector to a data.frame or tibble, I'm using `dplyr::bind_rows` below to accomplish this but equally `data.frame(as.list(summary(.$mpg)))` could be used instead.

```r
suppressWarnings(library(tidyverse))

mtcars %>%
  group_by(cyl) %>%
  nest() %>% 
  summarise(stats = map(data, ~ bind_rows(summary(.$mpg)))) %>% 
  unnest(stats)
#> # A tibble: 3 x 7
#>     cyl Min.    `1st Qu.` Median  Mean     `3rd Qu.` Max.   
#>   <dbl> <table> <table>   <table> <table>  <table>   <table>
#> 1     4 21.4    22.80     26.0    26.66364 30.40     33.9   
#> 2     6 17.8    18.65     19.7    19.74286 21.00     21.4   
#> 3     8 10.4    14.40     15.2    15.10000 16.25     19.2
```

<sup>Created on 2021-04-19 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>